# Jackson XML deserialization of specified tags only

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, deserialization, fasterxml

I am currently attempting to deserialize an RSS channel using Jackson FasterXML on Kotlin.

An RSS feed looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="/shared/bsp/xsl/rss/nolsol.xsl"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title><![CDATA[BBC News - Home]]></title>
        <description><![CDATA[BBC News - Home]]></description>
        <link>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/</link>
        <image>
            <url>https://news.bbcimg.co.uk/nol/shared/img/bbc_news_120x60.gif</url>
            <title>BBC News - Home</title>
            <link>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/</link>
        </image>
        <generator>RSS for Node</generator>
        <lastBuildDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2018 13:30:27 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <copyright><![CDATA[Copyright: (C) British Broadcasting Corporation, see http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/help/rss/4498287.stm for terms and conditions of reuse.]]></copyright>
        <language><![CDATA[en-gb]]></language>
        <ttl>15</ttl>
        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[Theresa May: Tories must be a party for everyone]]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[Theresa May pledges to boost council house-building and says austerity is over, in her big speech.]]></description>
            <link>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-45725615</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-45725615</guid>
            <pubDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2018 13:14:22 GMT</pubDate>
            <media:thumbnail width="976" height="549" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/0CCE/production/_103687230_hi049731823_crop.jpg"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[May dances on to stage to Abba ]]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[With a nod to stage malfunctions and the cough which dogged her 2017 Conservative conference speech, Theresa May danced her way on to the 2018 stage.]]></description>
            <link>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-45733091</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-45733091</guid>
            <pubDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2018 11:14:17 GMT</pubDate>
            <media:thumbnail width="768" height="432" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/18EA/production/_103687360_may2.jpg"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[Skripal poisoning: Putin denounces ex-spy as 'scum']]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[Russia's president complains the media are spending too much time on the man poisoned in Salisbury.]]></description>
            <link>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-45732221</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-45732221</guid>
            <pubDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2018 13:19:34 GMT</pubDate>
            <media:thumbnail width="976" height="549" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/1692/production/_103687750_049734043-1.jpg"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I am only interested in deserializing the following:

```
Channel:
    Title
    Link
    Image
Item:
    Title
    Description
    Link
    pubDate
    media:thumbnail
```

Currently I am able to deserialize this XML string just fine - however I need to explicitly state what tags I want to ignore using
`@JsonIgnoreProperties("generator", "ttl")` etc.

This is causing an issue however - as some feeds have extra tags and I can't go through every possible feed to manually enter which values to ignore.

I have attempted to solve this myself and have searched online for similar questions - yet I don't seem to find any questions or resolutions that match my issue.

Therefore my question is: Is there a way to deserialize only the specified tags and ignore anything else (without explicitly specifying which tags to ignore) using Jackson FasterXML or a similar framework?

Comment: You can by annotating with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`

Comment: @ThomasFritsch That's done the trick! Thanks for your help!